# how to reduce the time of sql taken?

Tags: sql, sqlite

i am beginner of use sql , there are two tables named photo and album in sqlite db and each has 80 thousand rows data.now I want get the forder info of every pics, i write sql :

```
SELECT *, album.RowId 
FROM photo,album 
WHERE photo.Path=album.Path 
    AND (photo.ThumbnailPath > '' or photo.Duration > 0) 
    AND photo.IsValid=1  
GROUP BY FolderPath 
ORDER BY Date DESC 
LIMIT 201
```

i use SQLiteStudio excute the sql string taken 0.3 second. but when i write c code use

```
gettimeofday(&onestart,NULL);
while (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(stmt)) {
  gettimeofday(&onestop,NULL);
  double onewhile = (onestop.tv_sec - onestart.tv_sec)*1000000 + onestop.tv_usec - onestart.tv_usec;
  SYSLOG(WARNING) << "one while taken " << onewhile / 1000.0 << " haos";
  onestart = onestop;
  std::cout<<"getAlbumList count is "<<result.size() <<std::endl;
  shared_ptr<BackupFileMetadata> metadata;
  try
    {
     metadata.reset(new BackupFileMetadata);
     unsigned index = fillBasicMetadata(*metadata, stmt);
     metadata->setThumbPath((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index++));
     metadata->isProcessed_ = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, index++) == 1;
     metadata->setPath((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index++));
     metadata->setName((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index++));
     metadata->setFolderPath((const char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index++));
     metadata->rowId = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, index++);

   }
   catch(...)
   {
     SYSLOG(ERROR)<<"getAlbumPhotos fill data ERROR!";
   }

  result.push_back(*metadata);
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

taken time:

```
one while taken 5241.04 ms
one while taken 0.778 ms
one while taken 0.555 ms
one while taken 0.536 ms
one while taken 0.528 ms
one while taken 0.62 ms
one while taken 0.607 ms
one while taken 0.626 ms
one while taken 0.589 ms
one while taken 0.559 ms
one while taken 0.538 ms
one while taken 0.531 ms
one while taken 0.524 ms
one while taken 0.512 ms
one while taken 0.522 ms
one while taken 0.524 ms
one while taken 0.522 ms
one while taken 0.631 ms
one while taken 0.606 ms
one while taken 0.544 ms
one while taken 0.528 ms
```

it taken 5 seconds to get 200 rows data!

i want to know why ? how can i reduce the time of my program taken ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYNmZ.png

Comment: Well, that's one of the drawbacks of using ORMs to query a database. Using pure SQL will always be much faster, since you're skipping a translation phase from `procedural` code to `set-based (structured query)` (SQL) code.